# C++ Mock Frameworks: 'Generic' vs 'Declarative'

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm recently learning a lot about Mocking Frameworks for C++, but there is one question which I couldn't solve so far:

There seem to be 2 different types of mocking Frameworks available (at least for C++):

- **Type Declarative:** Mock Frameworks like [Google Mock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) need every mock-class being defined via makros by hand
- **Type Generic:** Frameworks like [HippoMock](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks) provide a template-based method which creates a mock-object during runtime

I see that the Generic frameworks are a lot easier to use, the developer does not need to write every mock object himself. However there are a number of these Declarative frameworks available and especially Googlers usually know what they do. I ask why these frameworks exist and what the main advantages of them are over Generic frameworks.

Comment: I've never been using HippoMock or alike, but I like the way I can design the mock classes for GoogleMock exactly the way I need to behave them. If I need just simple mock classes the necessary overhead to declare them isn't too hard for the gain IMHO.

Comment: Another point: Can e.g. HippoMock handle template classes correctly?

Comment: May be 'declarative' would be a better term instead of 'rewriting', 'generic' is fine anyway ...

Comment: Sounds right, I'll edit it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that 'declarative' frameworks for mock classes make sense regarding the following points, what's intercessional for [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) for example is:

- No dependencies for any OS (I've been implementing a working version with FreeRTOS)
- Fine grained control for mock method handlers
- Fine grained control over expected method call results